# Dont return value with observable, from the service layer to the component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to pass the return of a service layer with subject to the components.

**My service that connects with api:**

```
 public getPerfilNew$(): Observable<PerfilInvestidor> {
            return this.http.get<PerfilInvestidor>(`${environment.api.basePosicaoConsolidada}/consolidado`)
              .pipe(
                map(res => res),
                shareReplay(1),
                catchError(err => {
                    console.log('Error in perfil', err);
                    return throwError(err);
                })
            )
        }

public getPositionConsolidated(): Observable<PosicaoConsolidada> {
    return this.http.get<PosicaoConsolidada>(`${environment.api.basePosicaoConsolidada}/consolidado`)
      .pipe(
        map(res => res),
        shareReplay(1),
        catchError(err => {
            console.log('Error investiments', err);
            return throwError(err);
        })
    )
}
```

**In my component: I tried it**

```
public loadData() {
        //find out if the profile failed or no
        this.homeGuardService.getPerfilNew$.pipe(
            takeUntil(this.unsubscribe) 
        ).subscribe(res => {
            this.perfilInvestidor = res;
            this.perfilFailed = this.perfilInvestidor.status ? true : false;
            console.log('perfil is failed --->', this.perfilFailed)
        })

        //checking for investments
        this.homeGuardService.getPositionConsolidated().subscribe(res => {
            this.positionConsolidated = res
            if (this.positionConsolidated) {
                this.investments = true
            }
        });


        this.isEverthingFailed = !this.investments && this.perfilFailed
}
```

I need external subscribe values ​​to match them in my variable **isEverthingFailed** teria que utilizar subject? BehaviorSubject? Because that way the variable **investments** and **perfilFailed**  is undefined

*With that amount of observables I compromise the memory? I'm open to suggestions*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use forkJoin or combineLatest to get both the streams and subscribe to them:

```
public loadData() {
  forkJoin([this.homeGuardService.getPerfilNew$(), this.homeGuardService.getPositionConsolidated()])
    .subscribe(([perfile, position]) => {
        this.perfilInvestidor = perfile;
        this.perfilFailed = this.perfilInvestidor.status ? true : false;
        console.log('perfil is failed --->', this.perfilFailed)
        this.positionConsolidated = position
        if (this.positionConsolidated) {
            this.investments = true
        }
        this.isEverthingFailed = !this.investments && this.perfilFailed
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: Iam edit question, I have new problem.

Comment: You are not returning anything currently. I updated my answer. apparently you want the perfil.status, so just return that.

Comment: I need to get data from other subscribes and combine them into an if, but when I try to make the logic out of subscribe the variables are undefined

Comment: yes this is asynchronous. You just need to do anything you need inside subscribe. There is really not enough information to what exactly more you want to do. There are lots of rxjs operators out there that can help you, but we dont know what your endresult should be.

Comment: But how can I leave the data inside the subscribe? I need to emit the value from inside the subscribe to use it in another method

Comment: why not subscribe then where you need it, in that function. Subscribe where you need it. You can combine streams if the other one is an asynchronous one as well.

Comment: I'll edit the question again, 1 minute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238873/discussion-between-guilherme-lucas-and-ajt82).

Answer (score 0):

**1. Questions**

There is no enough code here to see exactly what is happening. But at first glance it looks like a race condition from my point of view:

You have to realise how Subject works.

```
const sub = new Subject();
sub.next(1);

// If you subscribe here like:
   sub.subscribe(a => console.log(a))
// Nothing will happen because Subject does not preserve the old values
```

But if you do this:

```
const sub = new Subject();

// If you subscribe here like:
sub.subscribe(a => console.log(a))

sub.next(1);

// You will get a print in a console since you emitted the value after you subscribed on the stream.
```

In your case it looks like that you are subscribing to a subject after subject already emitted values.

Also:

```
 this.perfilClient$.subscribe(res => {
```

You are subscribing to this.perfilClient$, but i dont see where you are emitting values on that stream?

So if you cannot sync things that you subscribe to the Subject before it emits the value, you can use ReplaySubject or BehaviourSubject

**2. Questions**
You have just a few observables, its not much. But there are are some antipatterns such as:

1. Nesting subscribing
2. Subscribe callback function is empty
   etc..

The main thing in RXJs is to avoid side effects as much as possible.

Comment: Several components need to know if the this.perfilFailed is false or true, so I don’t want to do this in the component but in the core-state service, I edit question, but i have new problem